# UITableView Scrolling Performance and semitransparent views - does it matter only in the table?

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview

I have a UITableView which only takes like 3/4 of the screen, but not the entire screen. Now I wonder if it matters to scrolling performance a lot, if outside the UITableView there are views with alpha 0.5?

When a table view scrolls, is the entire screen affected with compositing and drawing, or only the frame of the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no noticeable performance hit with adjusting the alpha on any of the views.  Performance of UITableView is most effected by loading of individual cell views.  I temper this with the assumption that you are not creating a first person 3D shooter utilising TableView's. :)  If I have oversimplified your question, let me know.

Cheers,

Kenny

Comment: So what you say is, that it does not matter what alpha views outside the uitableview have?